# Play two videos from command line

Tags: video, vlc

I would like to be able to open and pause two videos starting at different times at the same time on the same screen from the command line or alternatively in a web page if this is easier.

For example open and pause Video1.mp4 at 53 seconds and open and pause video2.mp4 at 35 seconds, both video screens the same size, next to each other.

If possible, I would also like to add a custom name in the top of each video also from the command line.

If this is not clear I could attach a screen shot of what I am trying to achieve

I have got 70% of the way with VLC but have hit a block.

Comment: This is not a computer programming question.

Comment: Why don't you show the 70% you've achieved so far? Then we only need to help you with the remaining 30% rather than starting from scratch. Also which interpreter are you using? cmd? bash?